# How to convert a .nfo file to .fff

Tags: java, php, xml

I have an nfo file that I want to convert to HTML using https://github.com/imazen/folioxml. However, it requires .fff files. Does anyone know of a way to convert to fff from nfo? Also, if anyone has suggestions for a better way to do this, I am all ears. Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what `nfo` and `fff` files are? Do you want the solution to be written in Java or PHP?

Comment: i don't know what exactly do you mean by ```nfo``` files, but if they are the ones used in torrents, they can be treated as plaintext, as they mostly simple text files with ascii art. you can render them in html by wrapping itthe contentsn a ```pre``` tag, in a simple php script like this: ```<?php echo '<pre>'.file_get_contents('yourfile.nfo').'</pre>';```

Comment: Sorry there weren't any tags to describe this. In any language works. The nfo files are from an old folio infobase. I am wanting to preserve the files in some way. I will try file_get_contents and let you know if that works.

Comment: Hmmm that didn't work. All it did was output a string of numbers. @BalázsVarga I think I am just going to export my files as rtfs instead. Seems to be the simpler solution. Thank you for your advice though!